# Binding Failure on ToolBar Dragging

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, caliburn.micro

I have have a `ToolBar` which I am styling using the code shown below. I have come across three problems with the my `ToolBar` styling:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
    <Style x:Key="ToolBarToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}">
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon}"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding FullToolTip}" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding HasToolTip}" />
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked}" />
        <Setter Property="cal:Action.Target" Value="{Binding}" />
        <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="{Binding ActionText}" />
    </Style>
    ...
```

### First:

The tool bar images are currently getting used as a single static instance. Even with the property `x:Shared="False"` moving the `ToolBar` one over another will cause a rendering failure.

[image: Failure]

**Solution:**

In the ToolTip Styles.xaml, include the image source as a `ContentTemplate`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
    <Style x:Key="ToolBarToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image x:Shared="false" Source="{Binding Icon}">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Image">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
                                <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding FullToolTip}" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding HasToolTip}" />
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked}" />
        <Setter Property="cal:Action.Target" Value="{Binding}" />
        <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="{Binding ActionText}" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ToolBarButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image x:Shared="false" Source="{Binding Icon}">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Image">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
                                <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding FullToolTip}" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding HasToolTip}" />
        <Setter Property="cal:Action.Target" Value="{Binding}" />
        <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="{Binding ActionText}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now we have:

[image: Fix]

No other changes required.

### Second:

The same dragging procedure the `ToolTip` and `ToolTipService` bindings also get corrupted - at this stage I am not sure of the underlying reason. The quick solution is to do what I have done with the image above and add the `ToolTip` to the `Image`. However, this causes the `ToolTip` only to show when over the `Image` and not when hovering over the very edge of the button.

**Partial Solution:**

Add the `ToolTip` to the `Image`. However, this is not ideal as then the tool tips do not show when on the very edge of the button.

### Third:

When the drag operation shown above occurs, this also breaks the Caliburn property bindings

```
<Setter Property="cal:Action.Target" Value="{Binding}" />
<Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="{Binding ActionText}" />
```

**Questions: (Second and Third Problem)**

1. How to fix the problem with the `ToolTip` rendering?
2. How to fix the problem with the Caliburn property binding?

Thanks for your time.

---

### Solution:

"I've finally fixed this. As near as I can tell, when you initiate a drag on a toolbar, any toolbar items on other toolbars which are covered by the toolbar you're dragging get removed from their current position in the visual tree, and then (presumably) added back when they're made visible again.

When they're removed from the visual tree (again, that's what I think is happening), they also lose access to the ToolBarToggleButton and ToolBarButton styles, because those are defined in the Styles.xaml resource dictionary which is added in ToolBarsView.xaml.

However, if you define those same styles globally, then it works - presumably, even though they're no longer children of ToolBarsView, they still have access to the global resources.

So... I've added a new property, IModule.GlobalResourceDictionaries, which allows each module to declare any resource dictionaries that should be added at the global scope. The ToolBars module makes use of this."

https://github.com/tgjones/gemini/issues/67#issuecomment-60040008

Comment: It looks like some custom styling/templating is being applied to those toolbars--the color scheme doesn't look like it came from a system theme.  Have you tried stripping out the custom styles to see if that helps?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks very much for your reply. I will confirm this either way later tonight. I am currently away from my desk. Thanks again.

Comment: You description says you sold your *sole*, is that a touch of British juxtoposition humor on *soul*. ;-)

Comment: I love development, but mathematics/physics is my love. No money in it though... I am now combining the three in my spare time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to re-assign the tooltips as a style trigger for the mouse over event such as:

```
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding FullToolTip}" />
                   <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding HasToolTip}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                   <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding FullToolTip}" />
                   <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding HasToolTip}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
```

Comment: This looks promising! I will attempt this now... Any thoughts on the Caliburn bindings?

Comment: That worked well enough. If you can provide a solution to the third issue the bounty is yours sir. All the best.

Comment: @Killercam it is unclear (at least to me) what the Caliburn bindings are failing for this specific situation. Can you remove Caliburn from the equation and represent the problem in a generic way? That could provide two benefits, 1) in that it might localize the problem and provide insight into the failure and 2) provide a basic example for SO people like myself to tinker with....

Comment: @Killercam What about the Caliburn issue?...I hope that you were able to resolve it.